# Lottery Program in C++ won't win

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the number of times you need to buy a lottery ticket to win... but this program I created keeps running and never win's. I can't figure out why? I think it might be because of rand not producing true random numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, num5 = 0;
    int powerball = 0;

    int pnum1 = 0, pnum2 = 0, pnum3 = 0, pnum4 = 0, pnum5 = 0;
    int ppowerball = 0;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));

    int  max = 59;
    int pmax = 35;

    bool winner = false;

    int count = 0;


    while (winner == false) {
        count++;

        powerball = (rand()%pmax)+1;

        num1 = (rand()%max)+1;

        num2 = (rand()%max)+1;
        while (num1 == num2)
            num2 = (rand()%max)+1;

        num3 = (rand()%max)+1;
        while (num3 == num1 || num3 == num2)
            num3 = (rand()%max)+1;

        num4 = (rand()%max)+1;
        while (num4 == num1 || num4 == num2 || num4 == num3)
            num4 = (rand()%max)+1;

        num5 =(rand()%max)+1;
        while (num5 == num1 || num5 == num2 || num5 == num3 || num5 == num4)
            num5 = (rand()%max)+1;

        pnum1 = (rand()%max)+1;

        pnum2 = (rand()%max)+1;
        while (pnum2 == pnum1)
            pnum2 = (rand()%max)+1;

        pnum3 = (rand()%max)+1;
        while (pnum3 == pnum1 || pnum3 == pnum2)
            pnum3 = (rand()%max)+1;

        pnum4 = (rand()%max)+1;
        while (pnum4 == pnum1 || pnum4 == pnum2 || pnum4 == pnum3)
            pnum4 = (rand()%max)+1;

        pnum5 = (rand()%max)+1;
        while (pnum5 == pnum1 || pnum5 == pnum2 || pnum5 == pnum3 || pnum5 == pnum4)
            pnum5 = (rand()%max)+1;

        ppowerball = (rand()%pmax)+1;

        int myNumbers[] = {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5};
        sort(myNumbers, myNumbers + sizeof myNumbers / sizeof myNumbers[0]);


        int thereNumbers[] = {pnum1, pnum2, pnum3, pnum4, pnum5};
        sort(thereNumbers, myNumbers + sizeof thereNumbers/ sizeof thereNumbers[0]);

        if(myNumbers[0] == thereNumbers[0])
            if(myNumbers[1] == thereNumbers[1])
                if(myNumbers[2] == thereNumbers[2])
                    if(myNumbers[3] == thereNumbers[3])
                        if(myNumbers[4] == thereNumbers[4])
                            if(powerball == ppowerball){
                                winner = true;
                                cout << "Count: " << count << endl;

                                cout << num1 << "\t" << num2 << "\t" << num3 << "\t" << num4 << "\t" << num5 << "\tP: " << powerball << endl;
                                cout << pnum1 << "\t" << pnum2 << "\t" << pnum3 << "\t" << pnum4 << "\t" << pnum5 << "\tP: " << ppowerball << endl;
                                cout << endl;
                            }

        if(count%1000000 == 0)
            cout << count << endl;

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Count: " << count << endl;
    cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << " " << num4 << " " << num5 << "P: " << powerball << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you calculate the number of times? The algorithm

Comment: please ask a specific question you need help with - asking people to find the bug for you is not a specific question.

Comment: I count the number of times it loops with `count++;` if that is what you are asking.

Comment: You can't calculate the number of times you need to play to win. You can only calculate probabilities of winning.

Comment: @Pandrei I don't think there is a bug, I am asking if rand() could be the problem because it doesn't generate real random numbers...

Comment: @Arian I think the problem is simply that the changes of winning are so low that you need to let the program run for a very long time.

Comment: Doesn't generate real random numbers ?

Comment: Are you randomly picking both sets of numbers? The player's numbers and the winning numbers? If so this will probably run for months if not years before generating all the numbers to match.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Yes, I am picking both sets of numbers to be random.

Comment: Maybe my math is off (long time since probability class), but you are trying to get (randomly), one of 175,223,510 combinations?

Comment: @john and if they are low enough, the period of the *pseudo* random number generator might not be enough to catch the winning number, so you would end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: The number of ways you can pick a lottery is 59C5 (a very large number). Hence the probability of winning a lottery = 1 / (59C5) (very less).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to pick the "actual" numbers once, outside of the while loop, and then try to match the "winning" number inside the loop?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Yes, but in real life, people always ask for random numbers each week... So I want to see what happened in that real life scenario.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: no it doesn't. The probabilities are equal for true random numbers, but this exercise actually shows, that a bad PRNG doesn't produce a sequence of 5 numbers followed by the same 5 numbers  in any order.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen - my question was not about the accuracy of the random numbers at all, I was more inquiring about the actual scenario the OP was trying to simulate.

Comment: In real life there are two scenarios -- one, is that there's the single winning line and millions of tickets. The other is that every week or so, there's a new winning line and every week you buy a different coupon. Mathematically the probabilities are the same, but apparently they differ in practice. This tells something about the PRNG, since the program appears to be correct.

Comment: Try much smaller values for `max` and `pmax` first. Increase them a bit at a time, and you'll notice the problem with factorial growth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find one bug in your program I believe.

Your sort() method parameters are not correct. This was causing your arrays to be shifted and not sorted properly.

Try this instead:

```
int myNumbers[] = {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5};
sort(begin(myNumbers), end(myNumbers));


int thereNumbers[] = {pnum1, pnum2, pnum3, pnum4, pnum5};
sort(begin(thereNumbers), end(thereNumbers));
```

With this change I was able to get the program to actually match two numbers and exit.

Here I "won" on the 132,245,227th iteration when I ran your code with only the change mentioned directly above:

> ```
> Count: 132245227
> 32 57 24 4 23 P: 4
> ```

Comment: This doesn't fix the never winning